# IE8. overflow hidden + min-width: is there a workaround to this strange behavior?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, css

If we have floated div A, and div B with overflow: hidden next to it - div B should take all available space next to floated div. And if we have min-width set on the div B and window size is too small to keep this two divs on the same line - div B should wrap under the div A and take all available width of parent. This exact behaviour we can see in all major browsers except IE8, even IE7 handles it as expected. In IE8 when window size small enough so div B wraps under div A - div B not taking all available width but only have its min-width. The question is: is that a bug, or standard behavior? If this is a bug, how can we work around it?

I have a test case here: http://jsfiddle.net/BJM4s/2/ , resize the window to see it in action.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="A">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/100/100  " />                                                     
    </div>
    <div class="B">
       float float float float float float float float float float float float float float float float float float float float float float float float float float float float float float float float
     </div>
 </div>​
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    overflow:hidden;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 1px solid;
}


.A {
    float:left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.B {
    overflow:hidden;
    min-width: 200px;
    background: lime;
}​
```

Comment: If you can't figure it out, you can always put a HTML4 DOCTYPE header on the page and force it into IE5.5 "Quirks mode".  Then, maybe the page will behave the way you like?

Comment: @djangofan the page is too heavy, I need strict mode...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that adding `display: table-cell` to `.B` [**makes it behave**](http://jsfiddle.net/BJM4s/21/). I did not fully test in all other browsers to see if it would cause an issue. It might be best to just have it set for IE8 (though it did not seem to affect IE7/9 or Firefox).

Comment: One big downside is that if .B will contain long nonwrapping string (i.e. those strings with text-overflow:ellipsis) - .B will shrinks to contain all that string, not only visible part (standart table-cell behavior). But this is better than nothing. Will investigate further and then if nothing helps this will be the answer...

Comment: ...and also word without spaces that longer than min-width will wrap .B under .A. Nevertheless, accepted.